# Tomcat not being reloaded in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, tomcat

I am using Fedora 19 and using Apache Tomcat for running servlet programs.

I had some problems which I traced to the fact that once I made any changes to my program and recompiled, I had to restart the Tomcat server in order to affect the changes, i.e, I had to reload the server.

In Windows, the server is reloaded automatically if any changes are made, via a separate command prompt that opens "startup.bat".

In Linux, when I start "startup.sh" it just executes once and thereafter as I mentioned I have to restart the server manually.

Can anyone suggest what I should do for the Tomcat server to reload automatically on Linux after the changes are made?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know much about it. But there is a link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/serverxml.html saying the reloadable attribute is default set to true.

Comment: True. I got the solution. You need to add attribute `reloadable=true` in the context.xml file found in conf folder. You need to specify this attribute in the `<Context>` tag.